# ggplot2.barplot facets parameters not recognized

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using code taken directly from documentation page (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplot-easy-bar-graphs-in-r-software-using-ggplot2#faceting-split-a-plot-into-a-matrix-of-pannels)
R will not recognize documented parameters:

> ggplot2.barplot(data=diamonds, xName="clarity", 
>   +                 faceting=TRUE, facetingVarNames="cut")
>   Error: Unknown parameters: faceting, facetingVarNames**

Comment: (1) That is not the official documentation page, [this is](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html). (2) Did you load the `easyGgplot2` package as is instructed at the top of that webpage?

Comment: Furthermore: You might want to read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also be aware that ggplot2 has very recently been updated [blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/) and online documentation may not be up to date. Check the version you are loading.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the image below, I didn't get any error:

[image]

I would suggest to re-install easyGgplot2 package and to try it again:

```
 # Install
 install_github("kassambara/easyGgplot2")

 # Load easyGgplot2
 library(easyGgplot2)

 data(diamonds)

 ggplot2.barplot(data=diamonds, xName="clarity",  faceting=TRUE, facetingVarNames="cut")
```

Have a nice day!!

Best Regards,
AK

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would reproduce the first figure in the link given, without installing easyGgplot2, using ggplot2v2.0.0.

```
require(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity)) + 
  geom_bar() + facet_grid(cut ~ .)
p
```

[image: diamond plot]